# Tenses for two clauses joined by "if only"

Tags: grammaticality, subjunctive-mood, sequence-of-tenses, conditional-perfect

> 1. Our school had won the match if only we have concentrated.
> 2. Our school would have won the match if only we would have concentrated.
> 3. Our school would win the match if only we had concentrated.
> 4. Our school had won the match if only we would have concentrated.
> 5. Our school would have won the match if only we had concentrated.

Tell me which one is correct.

Comment: tell me guys...

Comment: 5 is correct. The first verb is the past subjunctive (subjunctive is a mood, not a tense), while the second is the pluperfect conditional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only sentence 5. is correct. Whenever *if only* is used in a dependent clause, the independent clause must take the conditional perfect (or present, etc.) tense.

Answer (score 2):

5 is the only correct one, but you have the additional near-miss on 3:

> Our school would win the match if only we concentrated.

A hypoethetical future result based on a possible current action, as opposed to the past/past combination you have in your statements.

Answer (score 1):

The fifth one is the only one which doesn't sound marked to me, as a native English speaker. I believe that some speakers of American would consider the second one acceptable too.

Comment: Sentence 2 would certainly be acceptable in French but certainly not in English :)

Comment: Indeed; "if I/you/we would have..." seems to be becoming more common, but that doesn't make it any more correct (yet)!

Comment: It would be nice if the person who voted this down explained why.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question from placement test, see:
http://fw.freshersworld.com/placementweek/showpaper.asp?cid=28&pid=14267&pgcount=1&prio=8

or

http://www.scribd.com/doc/47983144/CTS-Placment-Papers-20-jan-2010

The last one is correct.